# Does Boost::Jam (bjam) have a "question mode"?

Tags: makefile, codeblocks, bjam

I use Code::Blocks with Boost::Jam. A recent update to C::B added some new "custom makefile" commands, one of which is "ask if rebuild is needed". According to [this message](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=9941.msg69682#msg69682), it's meant to call `make` in a "question mode":

> -q, --question
>   ‘‘Question mode’’.  Do not run any commands, or print anything; just return an exit status that is zero if the specified targets are already up to date, nonzero otherwise.

Unfortunately, the Boost::Jam documentation doesn't mention such a mode in `bjam`. I've gotten around it by using this command for it...

```
bjam -error
```

...which forces `bjam` to return an errorlevel of 1 (because it doesn't recognize the option `-e`) and makes C::B always run the build command, but I'd prefer to use it as it was intended.

**My question:** does `bjam` have such a "question mode" and I just haven't found it, or is there some way in the Jamfile to make it work that way? The `-n` option doesn't work because it always returns zero, which C::B interprets as "all files up-to-date."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it doesn't.